# For...of loop Which Calls the Variable Name in a String

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-of-loop

Very new to JS and code in general (Less than a week, assume 0 knowledge base), so my explanation of the problem will be lack luster, but here's the rundown.

I have a function which takes the values of two obj. Arrays and adds the values together. It then sends that sum to a new array (allinit), and finally sorts the new array numerically. I need to keep them in numerical order and apply a unique string to each variable.

Using a second function (fun) and For...of loop I've generated the following:

```js
var allinit = [jim,dave,bob]

var fun = (allinit) => {

for (var element of allinit) {
    console.log( element + [the name of the variable] + 'initiative')
}
```

Using the first function I have assigned:

```js
var jim = 10  
var Dave =15   
var Bob = 20
```

How can I use this For...of function to print:

```js
10 Bob Initiative
```

*currently '10 initiative'*

by calling on the variable name that the element **10** represents?

The immediate answer will be to use a obj/key Array. However, as far as I know I cannot sort an obj/key Array and it MUST be sorted numerically after the sums have been calculated. I'm having a hard time keeping things fluid enough maintain the correct order while still being able to name the variables each number represents. I'm open to suggestions or printing my full code (~50 lines) for context.

### EDIT

Here is some shorthand of my code for context, keep in mind that this has many many lines removed from both arrays and the function. Theres probably about 6 variables in the function each with their own sum and .push()

```js
var R = {
  a:5,
  d:2
};

var B = {
  a:10,
  d:18,
};

var Start = (R,B) => {
  var allinit = [

  ];

  var ai = (R.a + B.a);
  allinit.push(ai);

  var di = (R.d + B.d);
  allinit.push(di);

  allinit.sort((a,b)=>a-b);


  var fun = (allinit) => {

    for (var element of allinit) {
      console.log( elemement+ ** Variable name here** + ' inititive')
      }
  };

  console.log(fun(allinit));

};
```

Comment: *as far as I know I cannot sort an obj/key Array* Sure you can - and doing that is by far the best method to use here

Comment: I think OP means "object" (i.e. `{Bob: 20, Jim: 15}`) with "obj/key Array", which aren't sortable, but an array-of-arrays (`[["Bob", 20], ["Jim", 15]]`) is sortable.

Comment: PLEASE point me to how I can do that. Google has not given me answers to how to sort an array outside of the basic .sort() which will kick back an error on an obj/key array.

Comment: @Gwynoak If you wouldn't mind, the full code would be nice for context here.

Comment: @AKX 

I edited the post with my code severely shortened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra context, since "initiative" is making me think about RPGs, I'm going to assume this is for something like that. I might be off-base here, but let's hope I'm not!

The idea here is that each player, currently their name and initiative value (but extensible for more things) is represented by an `{}` object, and they're in an `[]` array.

As you can see, I've deliberately ordered them in an arbitrary order, just so we can see sorting works as it should.

```js
var players = [
  {name: "Jim", initiative: 10},
  {name: "Bob", initiative: 20},
  {name: "Dave", initiative: 15},
  {name: "Uthorr the Star-Slayer", initiative: 3},
];

// Declare a callback for sort - named here for clarity.
function sortByInitiative(p1, p2) {
  // Sort into ascending initiative order (switch up `p1` and `p2` for descending).
  return p1.initiative - p2.initiative;
}

// Sort players in place.
players.sort(sortByInitiative);

// Loop over them and print salient information.
players.forEach((player, index) => {
  console.log(`Player ${index + 1} is ${player.name} with initiative ${player.initiative}!`);
});
```

The output is

```
Player 1 is Uthorr the Star-Slayer with initiative 3!
Player 2 is Jim with initiative 10!
Player 3 is Dave with initiative 15!
Player 4 is Bob with initiative 20!
```

Comment: Text book example of a good answer. I can offer an extended explanation of the sort function. It's sending in two parameters in `sortByInitiative`, that is two elements from the arrays (player items from `players`), and `sortByInitiative` is returning if one (p1) should be above the other (p2), based on the `initiative` in each object for each player.

Comment: While I absorb this answer, I posted some shorthand of my code. I am making an initiative tracker, so you're spot on there. It's meant to store a database of initiative bonuses. The user adds the rolls and the function finds the sum of R (roll) and B( bonus) to produce a list of numerically rated answers.

Comment: Then you might store the rolls in an array and the bonus as a number in the player object :)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand what you are going for, but it sounds like you want to use `Object.entries`, then sort based on the number, then deal with that.

```js
var jim = 10  
var Dave = 15   
var Bob = 20

console.log(
    Object
        .entries({Bob, jim, Dave})   // [['Bob', 20], ['jim', 10], ['Dave', 15]]
        .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]) // [['jim', 10], ['Dave', 15], ['Bob', 20]]
        .map((v) => `${v[0]} ${v[1]} initiative`)
        .join('\n')
);
```